# Getting specific fields of a model in another, via relationships between them

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship

I am working with the [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-manytomany-selects) for deploy specific forms fields based in the options selected in the same forms.
I have the following models:

`Session`, which have `ManyToMany` relationship with `Metrics`

`Session` model

```
class Session(models.Model):

    corporal_structures = models.ForeignKey(SingleBodySegment)
    movement = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Movements,
        chained_field = 'corporal_structures',
        chained_model_field = 'corporal_segments'
    )

    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metrics, blank=True)

    date_session_begin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    date_session_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    observations = models.TextField(blank=False
```

)

`Metrics` model

```
class Metrics(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
     equation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
     min_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=3)
     max_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=3)

     def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

Due to `ManyToMany` relationship, in the `Sessions` form (in django admin) I can see the list of the metrics of the `Metrics` model, but I just can see the `name` attribute of a `Metrics` instance in the form

[image]

I want get not just the `name` attribute, also I want get the `equation`, `min_value` and `max_value` attributes which are part of `Metrics` model

In the model/table `Metrics` is where I create a Metrics instance, but when I create a instance of `Session` model, I should denote a `Metrics` value for this `Session` instance, with the correspondent native fields such as:

[image]

How to can I get the other fields of the `Metrics` model and have them available in the `Session` form?

If I already associated `Metrics` and `Sessions` models with a `ManyToMany` relationship, this should will be useful for get it that I want, really?

I have been thinking that my doubt is more of the relationships topics and Django ORM instead the [django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-manytomany-selects) application.
I don't know if I am good in this previous affirmation

Any orientation will be appreciated.

Comment: Change `return "%s" % self.name` line in metrices model with `return "{},{},{}".format(self.name, self.min_value, self.max_value)`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj. If you want, you can post like answer in this question for I approve your answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the magic function `__str__` present inside the `Metrics` model like below.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{},{},{}".format(self.name, self.min_value, self.max_value)
```

This method overrides the default `__str__` function. So you may modify the return value according to your needs.